# Query dynamodb based on bool value

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have following query that works as expected:

```
var request = new QueryRequest {
        TableName = aTableName,
        KeyConditionExpression = "Username = :v_Username",
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
        {
           ":v_Username", new AttributeValue { S =  "admin@admin.com" }}}
        };
        var response = await _client.QueryAsync(request);
```

I have a column in my table that is a bool called IsAdmin. When i try to do same query for all rows where IsAdmin = true i get no results.

```
var request = new QueryRequest {
        TableName = aTableName,
        KeyConditionExpression = "IsAdmin = :v_IsAdmin",
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
        {
           ":v_IsAdmin", new AttributeValue { BOOL =  true }}}
        };
        var response = await _client.QueryAsync(request);
```

I don't see why this will not work?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a Query on an attribute which is not your partition key.

Commonly you would create a GSI to allow you to Query on attributes which are not keys, but in your case a bool is not allowed as a partition key:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

You would need to `Scan` the table in the current scenario and use a FilterExpression which would result in reading every item in the table which is inefficient and not scalable.

The best advice I can give is to use a string value for `isAdmin`. Only set a value for it if it is true. The create a GSI on `isAdmin` which will give you a sparse index only containing personnel who are admins.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html

Comment: So i decided to just create a new table for admins. Thanks for your advice

Comment: You're welcome, I do believe a sparse GSI would be your best choice, allow DynamoDB do the heavy lifting of creating that second view of just admins.